# Using CSS Grid to wrap two columns | max-content & minmax

Tags: css, css-grid

I am attempting to use Grid to display a two-column grid with the following attributes.

- Column One: Display `max-content` width (full length of text)
- Column Two; Take up the remaining space using `min-max(100px 1fr)`

The final attribute is to wrap the content onto two rows once the width rules are broken.

I've been struggling with this for the past day or so, it's something that should be simple!. 
But I still couldn't find a solution.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!. This is what I have so far.

```css
.grid-container-1 .grid-item-1 {
  grid-area:one;       
  background-color: red;
 
}

.grid-item-2 {
  grid-area:two;
  background-color: blue;
}

.grid-container-1 {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px 1fr));
  grid-template-rows:50px;
  grid-template-areas:
  "one two";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
     <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="grid-container-1">
   <div class="grid-item-1">This is the line that should show max-content</div>
   <div class="grid-item-2">This has a min width of 100px</div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you considered of using flexbox? It makes it much easier.

Comment: Grid is not meant to do this, flexbox is more suitable

Comment: Is it not possible with Grid at all?

I will explore solutions with Flexbox in the meantime.